# Scapy, can't get atribut 'name' value

Tags: python, scapy

Hello I discovered this scapy weird behaviour:

```
<pre>
>>> p[11][LEAP]
&lt;LEAP  version=1 reserved=0 length=24 data='[y\xda\xb8\xbfr\xedCN\xbc\xa8\xa7\x84Fk\xff\xb2\x8fn\x94(\x0c\x91\x8d' name='RSAINI' |>
>>> p[11][LEAP].data 
'[y\xda\xb8\xbfr\xedCN\xbc\xa8\xa7\x84Fk\xff\xb2\x8fn\x94(\x0c\x91\x8d'
>>> p[11][LEAP].name
'LEAP'
</pre>
```

When I want access attribute 'data' I get its value, but when I access attribute 'name' I get string 'LEAP' instead of 'RSAINI'. Can you please tell me how can I get the right value of attribute name?

Answer (score 0):

Karel,

What happens when you use

```
p[11].getlayer(LEAP).name
```

?

Comment: I pretty sure this is a viable answer and in my experience the preferred method, but suit yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved it this way: p[11][LEAP].fields["name"].